# Backing up multiple PCs in a network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, hard-drive, backup

### Background:

I have a small network that consists of roughly 10 PCs. Every week or so, we are required to backup all partitions of every PCs to one external HDD.

### Problem:

I find that the process is quite tedious since we can only do 1 backup at a time(Not to mention that our PCs are only running on USB-2.0 thus increasing the backup time even longer).

How can I possibly make this backup process faster? Surely there would be an easier way I guess.I can afford to buy new hardware if needed but I can't buy any paid software.

### My 2 Cents:

Add another PC to the network and do a network backup? Or is it even possible? How do I implement that?

NOTE: All PCs are running windows XP Professional 64-bits edition.

### EDIT:

Just to clarify, I am required to backup all the partitions as image files. And Currently I am using windows's imaging software.

Comment: What Backup software are you using at the moment or just windows imaging?

Comment: Why do you want to back up every pc in you small network? Because there are important files you work with every day? If yes i would consider buying a NAS(Network area Storage) and using this as a file server to save all important files. You should also be able to back up the NAS using a external HDD.

Comment: @CharlesH@Ivan Pls see the edit

Comment: I would seriously look at network attached storage solutions. It may be costly up front, but you'll save yourself a lot of time and headache which will make the investment pay off fairly quickly. As an alternative, there are options such as glusterFS which can make it so all the machines actually work off the network storage and you only have to back up the storage itself (which you can do with snapshots and/or with sync to a glusterfs DR system).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Windows will happily back up to a SMB share (I currently have backups going to a raspberry pi, though you want something with a bit more grunt), and most backup software will back up to any either a SMB share or a mapped smb share with a drive letter.

I'd suggest having a *fast* network interface - preferably gig-e betweem systems if you have many systems, and trying to schedule the backups at intervals so they don't all back up at once. On my systems I either back up late at night on a designated day, or during lunch.